# database logical full backup export using expdp

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, oracle-dump

I wrote the following commands:

```
create directory orcl_full as '/oradata3/datapump/full_export';
create user user1 identified by admin12;
grant read,write on directory orcl_full to user1;
grant exp_full_database to user1;
```

But when I tried exporting data using `expdp` command, it did not work:

```
expdp user1@ri/admin12@ORCL directory=orcl_full dumpfile=orclfull.dmp logfile=full_export.log FULL=YES;
```

Here is the error I get:

> ORA-31626: job does not exist
> ORA-31633: unable to create master table "user1.SYS_EXPORT_FULL_05"
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 1048
> ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'

I am stuck here, can someone kindly help me. In the tutorials, this command was working.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it did not work'? Did you get any error?

Comment: yes. ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-31633: unable to create master table "user1.SYS_EXPORT_FULL_05"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 1048
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'

Comment: After writing this command: expdp user1@ri/admin1234 directory=orcl_full NETWORK_LINK=source_database_link dumpfile=orclfull.dmp logfile=full_export.log FULL=YES;  error : ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-31633: unable to create master table "user1.SYS_EXPORT_FULL_05"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 1048
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ORA-31626: job does not exist
>   ORA-31633: unable to create master table

Datapump uses a master table to manage the export job. Like any other table it needs storage which means it needs to write to a tablespace.

> ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'

When you created `user1` account you did not grant it any tablespace privileges. So it cannot create any tables and that's why the job fails. The solution is quite simple: grant quota on the USERS tablespace (the default tablespace if no other is specified for the user account).

```
alter user user1 quota unlimited on users;
```

---

> "got the following error :SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "expdp use..." - rest of line ignored. "

`expdp` is an OS executable. Your error is a SQL*plus error, which is a SQL client. Either fire up a terminal window and run the OS command there, or shell out from SQL*Plus using the `host` command.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your kind help, but I wrote that command and got the following error :SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "expdp use..." - rest of line ignored. Kindly help me.

Comment: oh yes my bad... But I got the following error this time :ORA-39006: internal error
ORA-39065: unexpected master process exception in DISPATCH
ORA-04054: database link SOURCE_DATABASE_LINK does not exist
ORA-39097: Data Pump job encountered unexpected error -4054.

Comment: That's a separate issue, please ask it as a new question. . As my answer appears to have solved your original problem please upvote and accept it. Accepted answers improve the value of SO as a resource for future seekers.

Answer (score 0):

This command worked :

```
expdp user1@ri15/$d_pass directory=orcl_full dumpfile=orclfull.dmp logfile=full_export.log FULL=YES;`
```